# How to defend yourself against blood magic

Tags: magic, creature-design

How to defend against bloodmancers?

Bloodmamcers are an intelligent agglomeration of multiple microscopic organisms working in a colony.

Those organism can change shape to resemble a liquid or stand up in the shape of man being able to switch various cells around. Specifically they can change color perfectly to match the texture of clothes or human skin.

You may see a pond of water lying on the ground and the next second it morphs into a man.

Bloodmancers get their name because they can both enter humans through the veins and eat them from within, and also because they release some magical spores or air thingies which, when breathed in or coming in contact with the skin, make the person a slave to the bloodmancer.

The bloodmancer will be able to control from a distance (3 to 16 meters) the blood of the infected causing asphyxiation, moving limbs on their will, or simply increasing the blood pressure enough to blow up an artery.

The spores can travel for miles, and a skilled bloodmancer could infect an entire village from a large distance, then come and take control over the entire village either by literary commanding every single limb in their bodies like a puppet or extorting them in exchange of not being exploded.

How do normal humans living in a medieval fantasy setting defend themselves against being killed and/or enslaved by bloodmancers?

Comment: What is the setting? Modern day, that would probably be some form of hazmat suits. Medieval, might need to go the plague doctor way. The solutions would vary.

Comment: Is there an equivalent "zephyr-mancy" that can harmlessly disperse the spores upwards in a wind-devil? We could do with more details of the way your world works to tell us how to approach an answer.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you can [edit] your question to better fit our ways as per the [help]. It'll automatically enter the reopen queue and stand a chance of getting reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Infection and Immunology:

A bloodmancer is a foreign disease, rather than a being. It functions as numerous unicellular organisms coordinating. So they are going to be acutely vulnerable to the immune system.

1. A whole bloodmancer directly flooding a body is like eating someone - how do you defend against an amorphous being trying to eat you? Flight, fire, and unbroken skin. Start with loose continuous clothes sealed with (oil/wax/compounds harmful to bloodmancers but harmless to people). Galoshes would be critical. Shed or chemically treat outer clothes as needed. Possibly carry oil and/or vinegar/lye with you to rinse it off, make your skin resistant, etc. A good lye soap would do the trick as well. Simply running away is likely to be a great option, as these things are amorphous and likely to be less mechanically able to move fast. Then (again) rinse/wash with harsh chemicals.
2. Secondly, I find it hard to swallow (pun intended) that this thing can control whole villages via spores. This thing is operating like a colonial organism, and the more it spreads, the less coordinated it will be. Parts will start operating independently at the least, and be quite unintelligent until they can acquire knowledge. So the wider they spread, likely the less effective they will be. They may even suffer a sense of disintegration and loss of identity if too broadly spread. That's up to you.
3. Further, the spores are VERY tenuous - like an infection. Your body will respond to them like it would an illness. There will be attempts by the body to make the body an undesirable environment for the invader, and the immune response could be different from ours if these things have been in the environment of people for a long time. Fevers, swelling at infection sites, and immune attacks on the spores mean they stop working after a time. People previously exposed will likely become immune. The body might induce paralysis as a response to these spores, rendering people vulnerable but unable to obey (until the immune response kicks in and fights off the invader).
4. Finally, these things are part of the environment. If people have noticed that those infected with blood pox (a related organism) are resistant to domination by spores, they will spread blood pox to folks in areas the bloodmancers are operating. It would likely make them resistant to domination and make the resulting humans hard to eat OR at least a bitter human to swallow.

**Variables:** Depending on the specifics of your organisms, there are a variety of strategies to help people deal with them. If there is something bloodmancers are intolerant of, like tomatoes (in the nightshade family, one of which is the tomato; humans are resistant to the one in tomato fruits) then suddenly everyone is eating tomatoes and drinking tomato juice is a custom to be done with strangers. All food is likely to be cooked, washed, canned, marinated and blanched - whatever can destroy spores. Boil water, BTW.

If the shape shifting is hard, maybe they can imitate humans, but not individuals - suddenly strangers are not trusted, and must be vetted. People would follow a buddy system and go out in socially distancing groups, so a single person ambushed can either be rescued, mercy-killed, or simply reported as lost and untrustworthy. Perhaps bloodmancers find vocal chords challenging - their voices might not sound right. Vocal greetings become a critical custom. Maybe they can copy water, but water would be very challenging for a colonial organism. Moats are important, and washing hands with strong soap in front of people is customary.

Architecture would be important - otherwise these things could creep up on people as they slept and eat/copy/enslave them. Houses on stilts with the stilts wrapped in something resistant (vinegar rags?) or placed over water (if water works) would make sleep safe. Walls would be filled with caulking. Fires would be placed in many places (simple for a medieval world) to allow rapid deployment of fire, coals, ash, and the like. Night watchmen in bloodmancer-climb-resistant 20 meter towers keep watch for shenanigans of these evil pests - cries for help, mysterious goings-on, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Any sufficiently large advance in evolution is indistinguishable from a doomsday weapon.  You have described an organism with instant development, extraordinary reproductive capabilities, and a virtually supernatural ability to maintain at least human intelligence while entirely reorganizing itself.  Unless the world's worst movie writer makes them die when the rain hits them, they are not going to lose the evolutionary contest.

Given that this is a doomsday weapon, your solution needs to embrace that.  You have to wipe out every speck of life in the region.  Unless you have a massive gamma sterilization gun in space, you may need to call in this biotechnology on your side.  Mutate the organisms' genome so that it focuses purely on reproduction and assimilation, make it even more virulent, a "gray goo" that converts every living thing to more of itself, but consider limiting its range a bit if you can so that some natural obstacles might stop it.  Attempt to flee beyond a large natural barrier, i.e. find an island, before it is released.

Answer (score 2):

**Distance.  And assorted dogs.**

> /The bloodmancer will be able to control from a distance (3 to 16
> meters)/

Bloodmancers can either physically infect people thru contact, or enslave them from a distance with spores.  Spores can travel a long way but to actually effect control the bloodmancer has to pretty much be sitting in your lap.  16 meters is not that far.

If you can keep away from bloodmancers it does not matter if they infect you with magic spores because they need to be close to make you dance even though you are a bad dancer and people will laugh.  That is why they do it, those wicked bloodmancers.

Yes.  So gates, and dogs.  The gates keep the bloodmancers at a distance from the humans and the dogs growl at bloodmancers because even though they look like superhot hotties they smell like braunschweiger and even small inbred dogs can tell.  You dont let those people in to your city.  Not even the hotties!  Were you listening?

But but but but!  you say because you want them to be uber bad, these blood sausages.   But what if you are out hoeing your field and the person who comes up is not super hot but looks like your own brother!  He is actually pretty easy on the eye too, Bob is, but I keep several inbred small dogs with me even in the fields and of course they would run up to check out my brother who always gives them treats and good scratches.  But this is a Bloodmancer pod brother and they can tell.

I run, keeping 16 meters between us.  If it cant touch me it cant infect me and assuming I have magic spores in me, if it is 20 meters away it cant make me dance.   The dogs (good brave little dogs!) run interference for me nipping at my fake brother, gnawing his fake genitals and calling the big dog who was doing something in the woods but can move fast when events warrant.

Yes, dogs and distance will be the end of the Braunschweigermancers.

Answer (score 1):

Bloodmancer spores have flagellum, microscopic tails which can spin like a motor, allowing them to move through calm air with complete control of their direction and speed.  The instincts which determine navigation however are very primitive, simply targeting the hottest nearby object.

People who live near bloodmancers always carry torches to attract the spores like mosquitos to a bug zapper.  They also watch for the colored sparks within the flames which appear as the spores incinerate.  Sparking fire is a sign of trouble to come and the wise will tie bandanas over their mouth and nose (and drop a silken veil over their eyes) whenever sparks rise.

Detecting a bloodmancer in your midst can be challenging because they can appear perfectly human, but a simple blood letting tells the tale.  When you cut a person, blood drops from the wound and completely leaves the body.  Bloodmancers cannot mimic this effect because the conglomerate portion which makes up a detached drop of blood will die when it leaves the collective.  Each portion of the bloodmancer has a survival instinct which prevents it from self-sacrifice, so the closest that a bloodmancer can do is bleed out onto its skin or open blood drip down their arm.  The drops just won't fall off.

Another great method for detecting and even harming a bloodmancer is magnetism.  Every fluid cell of their bodies is full of iron.  They are even more iron-rich than normal human blood, so magnetic fields can distort their forms and even rip them apart when strong enough.  There is no way for a bloodmancer to remain disguised  in the presence of a strong magnet, and even a mild magnetic field on an sword or dagger is enough to make it effective against the usually fluid bloodmancer form.

The best defense against bloodmancers is avoidance.  As colonial life forms, their senses of sight and hearing are very limited.  The complex orchestration of structure and function necessary to enable clear distance sight or directional hearing are beyond the abilities of most bloodmancers and even those who can do it must concentrate on just that one sense to make it work properly.  They hunt by sense of smell and by an unfocused infrared sense which is instinctively implemented by the outer layer members of their conglomeration.  These senses evolved as part of their natural (presentient) hunting method which is the trapping of unwary creatures which attempt to drink from their puddle form.

Advanced bloodmancers have been known to derive another sense through interaction with their magical spores.  The spores can also exhibit the sense of smell and the unfocused infrared heat detection, and through a bloodmancer's telepathic link to their spores, they can receive vague input from the spore senses.  This spore-based far-sight is somewhat distorted as the individual spores do not know their exact locations relative to each other, so the sense information gathered is unorganized at best.  Extremely advanced bloodmancers are rumored to exist who can send out a small coordinated pack of spores which fly together and report back coherent sensory data, but such reports are unsubstantiated.  It may be that such coordinated spore packs can also avoid destruction by flame and bypass simple facial shielding which would explain why few humans survive to report on this advanced bloodmancer ability.

Ultimately, the best defense when you see a bloodmancer or even a sparking flame is to take your torch and run.  Chances are you have seen them before they have sensed you.

Answer (score 1):

Give the bloodmancer motives.  Or approximations thereof.

Thus far you have given them the ability to act like a plague.  The thing is, diseases mutate to be LESS dangerous because any disease that wipes out all the people that catch it is extinct very rapidly.

If bloodmancers want to kill us all off out of sheer malice, we have a real problem.  But what on earth do they can by wiping out entire villages except fewer people to prey on?  In real life, the predators are always vastly outnumbered by the prey by the very nature of predation.

Also, your bloodmancers have to move secretly and kill with stealth because they need to eat the next day and do not want everyone to run away.  Spores that travel for miles will only work if they hit on a human at the right time, and furthermore are a lot of effort for a small gain; it would be simple for a bloodmancer to use up all its energy to get one human, not enough to replenish it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your technological level?

The bloodmancers seem to lack skin - in other ways, an impenetrable barrier to many chemical agents.  Spray them with disinfectants - or, in  medieval settings,  distilled alcohol, or even strong wine or vinegar could be enough. Depending on the exact nature of the bloodmancers, it might caue them unbearable pain, or just kill enough of them at the outer layers to make the structure collapse ald lose their integrity.

As for the remote control, it depends on the mechaniism  - is it radiomagnetic? Either use a jammer (problem solved), or wrap yourself in tinfoil. Or, in medieval settings, full body plate armour. And have a flask with some alcohol ready.